# classification in arulesCBA package

Tags: r, classification, arules

I am applying arulesCBA package in R on dataset with 2 classes. It generates the rules with the classes on RHS, but I am asking about how to classify a new dataset based on these rules.

Answer (score 0):

Models are applied in R using the `predict()` function. You should read the manual page for CBA (`?CBA`). There is an example for creating predictions.